# $\int_{0}^{1} f(x,y)g(y)dy=0$ for a.e. $x\in [0,1]$ with $g\in C[0,1]$ implies $f=0$ a.e. on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory

I'm stuck on a measure theory problem and need some hints. Let $S=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ be the unit square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f\in L^1(S)$. Suppose that for any $g$ continuous on $[0,1]$ we have $\int_{0}^{1} f(x,y)g(y)dy=0$ for a.e. $x\in [0,1]$. Then $f=0$ a.e. on S. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think using Weirstrass approx., or just use the case g=1 on S

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

For any $h$ continuous on $[0,1]$, we can say
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) h(x) g(y) dx dy = 0.$$
What does the Stone-Weierstrass theorem say about the set of all continuous functions on $[0,1]^2$ which are of the form $h(x) g(y)$?

Comment: Very nice hint. +1.

Comment: @Nate This is the idea that comes to mind when considering your hint but it seems tedious so let me know if there's a better way. Approximate indicator functions by functions in $C(S)$ which are in turn approximated by functions of the form $h(x)g(y)$ as you say. This is done in the $L^{1}$ norm. This leads to $\int_{S}\mathbb{1}_{B}f=0$ for all Borel sets $B$. This implies $\int_{S}|f|=0$ after considering that $\int_{S}\mathbb{1}_{f\geq 0}f=0$ and $-\int_{S}\mathbb{1}_{f<0}f=0$. Now it follows that $f=0$ a.e. on $S$.

Comment: @Bones: First, note that it's *linear combinations* of functions of the form $h(x)g(y)$ that are dense in $C(S)$.   Also, $L^1$ approximation is not quite what you want, but a.e. approximation would work; you can take the approximating sequence to be uniformly bounded (why?) and then use dominated convergence.  Otherwise, what you say is pretty much equivalent to what I had in mind.